# htaccess clean url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change my url to:

```
www.xxxx.com/en/ -> index.php?lang=en
www.xxxx.com/news -> index.php?mod=news
```

I use this code but it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(pe|en|fr|sp|ar)/$ 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?lang=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(pe|en|fr|sp|ar)$ 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=$1
```

`var_dump($_GET)` result :

```
array(2) { ["mod"]=> string(9) "index.php" ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) "e7a5fc683653b7eea47a52dfc64cd687" }
```

I also use htaccess tester ( http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ ) and all things were ok! :(

Answer (score 1):

*Both* rules pass, and are therefore applied. The first rewrites `/en/` to `/index.php?lang=en`. Then the second rule passes, and rewrites to `/index.php?mod=index.php`.

Use the `[L]` option to stop processing once a given rule passes:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(pe|en|fr|sp|ar)/$ 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(pe|en|fr|sp|ar)$ 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @Hamid: really? I ran it through the htaccess tester you provided, and got the expected result.

Comment: it's work on htaccess tester but it didn't work on my server!:(

Comment: @Hamid: are the rules being ignored entirely? You may need `RewriteEngine On` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You're capturing the index.php.  Ignore existing files and directories, and stop processing rules with `[L]`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(pe|en|fr|sp|ar)/$ 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]

# Don't rewrite index.php or other existing file/dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(pe|en|fr|sp|ar)$ 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works fine for me:

```
RewriteRule ^(pe|en|fr|sp|ar)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:pe|en|fr|sp|ar)/)([^/]*)$ index.php?mod=$1 [L]
```

1. You definitely have to use `[L]` flag in such situations
2. I got rid of `RewriteCond` in first rule -- the pattern is simple enough and no need in having separate condition (which means 2 matches has to be done instead of 1 in my implementation).
3. In second rule use `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` to check if requested resource (original or already rewritten) in not a real file/folder and only then rewrite. This will prevent that double rewrite that you facing.
4. I have also got rid of `RewriteCond` here as rule is not too complex (it's more difficult to read, especially if your regex skills are not great, but it is working). This also makes my answer a bit different to already provided :)